# What would you do to protect yourself from phone radiations?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, biology

It's object of debate whether cell phones' radiations cause cancer after prolonged use, specially when the phone emits at its maximum power and it is closely attached to the body. Like for example I have found this question: [Could cell-phone radiation cause cancer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/could-cell-phone-radiation-cause-cancer)

My thought on the issue is that at the moment it is not proven that cell phones are safe, so I would like to take some precautions until it's 100% proven that it is safe to wear it in your pocket.

I can see that there are already phone covers on the market, advertised as shields from radiations but they are also a matter of debate, as not everybody agrees that they protect your body from radiations.

My question is more practical rather than technical like this one: [Could an attachment to cell-phones limit or neutralize electro-magnetic radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104193/could-an-attachment-to-cell-phones-limit-or-neutralize-electro-magnetic-radiatio)

I am asking what is the set of precautions that you would take to protect your body. I already know that a recommendation could be to use wired earphones while having a phone call, or to turn it off when traveling by car or train. But what to do in order to carry it safely while walking? would you recommend wearing it in a bag or a belt pouch? or any special device made on purpose to carry it?

Comment: I would do nothing. In full sun you are being hit by roughly 1000W/m$^{2}$ of electromagnetic energy, some of which (e.g. UV-C) is known to cause cancer. Your phone puts out a small fraction of the 1000W, and no UV at all. Note that over the last 40 years, as the number of cell phones has gone from 0 to billions, there has not been a huge increase in cancer rates (of any kind).

Answer (score 4):

There are I think only two ways to prevent your body from phone radiations. The first one is as @Yejus said creating a Faraday Cage. You can make a very cheap one with aluminium foil. The problem for this solution is that it will block electromagnetic fields emitted by your phone, but also the ones that it is supposed to receive, making your phone useless.

The other solution, the simplest to my opinion, is to turn the phone off when you don't want to use it. It may appears as a dumb solution, but I think it is the cheapest, the simplest to do with the best results.

Answer (score -1):

My instinct tells me to put my phone in a copper box -- essentially a [Faraday Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). Copper is a metal, so it will screen out electric fields. Further, copper is diamagnetic, so it will also repel magnetic fields. That should be sufficient to block out most if not all of the electromagnetic waves coming out of the phone.

If the box is not much bigger than the phone itself, it could be viable to keep one's phone in it and then put the box in one's pocket when not in use.

Comment: Won’t this block both incoming and outgoing calls and texts ? In which case, why not just turn the phone off ?